# Magento2.3: Is it possible to create multiple My-account dashboard?

Tags: magento2.3, account-dashboard, myaccount

In my site, we have 3 types of customer groups and want to show the separate My-account dashboard for those customer after they logged-in.

In order to achieve, do we need to create separate dashboards?

Hope you have understood my question.

Any help will be appreciated!